# Vue.js 2.0 router link in a div component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I can link like this in `vue.js 2.0`:

```
<router-link to="home">Home</router-link>
```

This compiles to an `a` tag. But how do I do this with a div?

With `vue.js 1.0` I did it like this:

```
<div v-link="{ name: 'Messages', params: { topic: topic.slug }}">test</div>
```

That's obviously not working anymore.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, [`router-link`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html) has a `tag` prop. You're looking for this:

```
<router-link to="home" tag="div">Home</router-link>
```

Answer (score 9):

### The Vue Way

If you want `<router-link>` to render as another tag, in your case `div`, you can use [tag prop](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html) to specify which tag to render to, and it will still listen to click events for navigation.

```
<router-link to="home" tag="div">Home</router-link>
```

---

You can also do this via one of pure HTML ways:

### Way 1

```
<a href="/home">
    <div>
        Home
    </div>
</a>
```

### Way 2

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='/home';">
    Home
</div>
```

You can also modify second way in vue way as following:

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;" @click="redirectToHome">
    Home
</div>
```

where you can define `redirectToHome` method as following:

```
methods: {
  redirectToHome () {
     this.$router.push(
        {
          path: '/home',
        }
     )
 },
```

Comment: Very strange that vue.js deprecated that.  This is devious.

Comment: @Jamie Deprecated what?

Answer (score 7):

## Vue.js 3

Disclaimer: the question is about Vue.js 2. I saw that.

- `tag` attribute [is no more](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link)

Instead, do a `v-slot` such as:

```
<router-link to="/about" custom v-slot="{ navigate }">
  <div role="link" @click="navigate">test</div>
</router-link>
```

- `custom` prevents the creation of an `a` element
- `navigate` is the function provided for the `div`, to activate navigation
- `role="link"` is accessibility stuff (you could omit it), but can also be used for CSS'ing the hand mouse cursor

CSS:

```
[role="link"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

One could also just let the `a` remain, since browsers are now better at dealing with a `display:block` `a`, but that's another story.

Comment: This does not work for me, when clicking, the navigate call does not anything. If I add an alert it does call alert though. Note that without adding the `custom` tag it works (but it wraps the div inside a `<a>` tag)